# GAE Implications of NDB hierarchy and entity groups

Tags: python, google-app-engine, data-structures, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to better understand the implications of the deep hierarchy described in the [GAE NDB docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities)

"For example, a revision of a message that "belongs to" an owner, might have a key that looks like"

```
rev_key = ndb.Key('Account', 'Sandy', 'Message', 'greeting', 'Revision', '2')
```

I interpret this to mean that if I do `Revision(parent=rev_key).put()` then I will have an entity group at the Revision=2 level meaning ancestor queries where `ancestor=rev_key` will have strong consistency and writes where `parent=rev_key` will be limited to 1/sec.

But what are the implications further up the hierarchy?

For instance, say I have

```
rev_key_B = ndb.Key('Account', 'Sandy', 'Message', 'greeting', 'Revision', '3')
```

Is write speed limited to 1/sec at the `rev_key_B` level or, since they share a parent's parent, i.e. `ndb.Key('Account', 'Sandy', 'Message', 'greeting')`, is write speed limited even higher up the ancestor path and, ultimately, to the entire entity group all the way up to `ndb.Key('Account', 'Sandy')`?

Same questions re: strong consistency. Would `Revision.query(ancestor=ndb.Key('Account', 'Sandy', 'Message', 'greeting'))` have strong consistency?

Comment: I swear there used to be text stating that an "entity group" is always a root entity plus all descendants (meaning the 1/sec limit applies to each root entity and all descendants, regardless of whether your ancestor queries are farther down the hierarchy or not). I can't find any reference to that now, though, so perhaps I misunderstood or it has changed.

Comment: There was a comment to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012302/ndb-hrd-transactions-which-ancestor-determines-the-entity-group) from @Daniel Roseman that claims an entity group is "everything under a root entity" but I didn't find it in the documents either. My comment to the answer is specifically about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see

```
rev_key = ndb.Key('Account', 'Sandy', 'Message', 'greeting', 'Revision', '2')
```

Means that every entity has strong consistency following the entity path. So you are correct.

Lets see it in action: Create the entities

```
account_sandy = Account.get_or_insert('Sandy')
sandy_message = Message.get_or_insert('greeting', parent=account_sandy.key)
sandy_message_rev = Revision.get_or_insert('2', parent=sandy_message.key)
```

That will give you strong consistency and grant you the ability to query all the above entities inside transactions as well.

I am using the `get_or_insert` which does what it says inside a transaction efficiently creating an entity if it does not exist with the key provided. This requires the key or id to be unique. So this way you cannot have 2 messages with `Greeting` and `Sandy as parent`.

The way keys work is like a binary tree.

S = Sandy, M=Message, R=Revision

```
    Sandy
   / |   \
  M1 M2   M3 
 / |  \   | \
R1 R2  R1 R1 R2
```

**Each path to the end or shorter can be run in transaction and provide strong consistency*.**

Reply in comment:

As this example is not sufficient to show the efficiency of GAE and NDB maybe the below will.

Imagine that you have a jukebox with queues per room let's say. And people are queueing songs to each queue of each jukebox.

J=Jukebox, Q=queue, S=Song

```
   Jukebox       
   / |   \        
  Q1 Q2   Q3     
 / |  \   | \
S1 S2  S3 S4 S5
```

In this example it is convenient to use paths, so each operation by a user, knowing wich jukebox, queue can CUD the song entity with consistency to jukebox, queue and song.

*Btw you can also lock paths not starting from root

Also keep in mind that [Queries inside transactions must include ancestor filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries)

Comment: Maybe this is just a contrived example by GAE to demonstrate capabilities but I don't see the point of having a hierarchy like this. If consistency is enforced at the root level, i.e. everything that shares the `account_sandy.key` ancestor then what's gained by having a Message and Revision layer? Why not just have `revision` be a property of `Message` and have all messages directly children of `account_sandy.key`?

Comment: @diddleboo you can have it as you describe as well in the message revision example. But then every time you want to edit a message then you lock all revisions as well. The point of having paths is to isolate consistency in a way that does not block the rest of the flow.

Comment: I guess that's my confusion still. Given the Jukebox tree you made and I update a song, say S1, what exactly **is** and **is not** locked?

Comment: @diddleboo whatever you please as long as it is in the path. Example you can lock the queue and a specific song in order to update play counts or archive the song to another queue. So it really depends. You can even lock all data down the root entity in case of massive scenario. Also the path does not require to start from root, but maybe knownledge of the key is.

Comment: **1)** In that case, is it accurate to say that the "locking" is established via the ancestor query? **(2)** Song.query(ancestor=J:Q1).fetch() will be strongly consistent and "lock" the entity group at Q1 and all its descendants while keeping the rest of the tree unlocked? **(3)** What about write constraints? Is it 1 write /sec for the entire Jukebox? How does this setup scale to the case where the Jukebox has thousands of queues with thousands of songs each and all the reading and writing that would occur?

Comment: @diddleboo  1) yes 2) yes 3) 1/sec I have no idea about this. On the scale always depends on the operation. Eg if you are talking about writes that occur not so often then yes it's fine. If you are talking about thousands or reads/writes per minute something like a counter then app engine **IS NOT FOR YOU** . App engine needs to be optimized for minimal of these. Each operation in write costs roughly 5 writes so a thousand would be 4 thousand and each node in the path would cost one more and so on. Ending in a long path having too many reads or writes. Simplify your perspective...

Comment: Re: 1 write / second [see here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency): "This approach achieves strong consistency by writing to a single entity group per guestbook, but it also limits changes to the guestbook to no more than 1 write per second (the supported limit for entity groups)." Also, FYI, I expanded on the topic a bit further in [this new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850508/gae-entity-group-data-modeling-for-consistency-and-performance), drawing on your Jukebox example.

Comment: @diddleboo will take a closer look after the holidays and help if possible

Comment: Thanks Jimmmy - I actually just updated it having found what I think is a better approach. Thanks for helping me get there:) Happy holidays.